# MSB6006 error "CL.exe exited with code -1073741819" caused by errors in code

Tags: c++, visual-studio, compiler-errors, cl

TLDR: Both IDE and compiler missed an error in code, it only got reported by this exit code.

After a minor edit to my code regarding virtual methods, I got the error above seemingly out of nowhere. Translating the exit code to hex gives 0xc0000005, an access violation. Same problem is being solved [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/56ea2264-ee0e-40b0-9c0e-bc3715fe54a7/microsoftcppwin32targets1475-error-msb6006-quotclexequot-exited-with-code-1073741819?forum=vcgeneral) and [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/92f96eba-1838-4d38-bb31-f861ce8f2dae/msb6006-8220clexe8221-exited-with-code-1073741819?forum=vcgeneral). According to those discussions, this may be caused by cl.exe being unaccessible for whatever reason, those reasons however do not apply in my case (I checked).

Another cause mentioned somewhere (I lost the link) is an error in project-specific settings. My other projects compiled with no problems, so I tried to fix that. Even when I created a new (copy of this) project, it worked. When I however moved all headers and sources to this new project, it started doing the thing again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to go back to where the error suddenly started appearing, and I found it. I am not sure how, but this error was caused by an incorrect piece of code I had written.

One of my headers contained two classes, one of which (base) was stand-alone as it was, but the other (derived) also provided a specific wrapper for it. Both had an identical method (same name and parameter list), which is probably not the best approach, but it seemed to compile with no problems.

```
class Base {
    void DoStuff(void*);
    void SetValue(bool);
}

class Derived : private Base {
    void* m_ptr;
    void DoStuff() { Base::DoStuff(m_ptr); }
    void SetValue(bool b) { Base::SetValue(b); }
}
```

Note that I did this because of the different parameters of `DoStuff`, otherwise I would just inherit publicly.

Then I decided to add an interface-like (abstract) class for convenience and the error started appearing.

```
struct Iface {
    virtual void SetValue(bool) = 0;
}

class Base : public Iface {
    void DoStuff(void*);
    void SetValue(bool) final;
}

class Derived : private Base {
    void* m_ptr;
    void DoStuff() { Base::DoStuff(m_ptr); }
    void SetValue(bool b) { Base::SetValue(b); }
}
```

Do You see the obvious mistake I am making here?

After removing the `final`, the code compiled again. The IDE did not catch my error, likely because both `Base` and `Derived` were actually templates, and neither did the compiler, and the first thing to complain was apparently CL, which gave this not-exactly-clear exit code.

Comment: You seem to distinguish between compiler and `CL.exe`. But the `CL.exe` is actually the **C**ompiler and **L**inker. So, in this case, it seems like the compiler had crashed (due to an access violation inside the compiler), as reported in that error message coming from the MSBuild (a build tool). Compiler crashing means there probably is a bug in the compiler. You should report this to Microsoft (and provide them with a reproducible example), so they could fix the compiler.

Comment: @heapunderrun I think `CL.exe` is only a compiler, the MSVC linker is `link.exe`, found in the same folder.

Comment: @M.A The filename of `CL.exe` probably comes from the first letters of words _compile_ and _link_. The `CL.exe` automatically calls `link.exe`. There is an option **`/c`** to prevent `CL.exe` from invoking the linker (in that case, `CL.exe` will only compile the source code into `.obj` files, and you can later manually execute `link.exe`). Actually, the MSVC compiler is implemented across several DLLs (`c1xx.dll` is C++ front end, `c2.dll` is back end; there is also `c1.dll` for C front end), but `CL.exe` is loading those DLLs and driving the compilation + linkage.

Comment: @heap Interesting, I was not aware of the structure of CL.exe.

Comment: I am glad you have got your solution and thanks for your sharing, I would appreciate it if you mark them as answer and this will be beneficial to other community.